# Object reference not set to an instance of an object error when upgrading content database

Tags: upgrade

I'm having trouble upgrading some content database to the June 2015 CU update. These databases were moved from on farm to another. They work, but when I try to run psconfig to update them I get the following error in the upgrade log.

> Upgrade Timer job is exiting due to exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have three databases that were moved giving the same error. It makes me think that there was an issue with the move itself.

We basically restored the databases from a backup to the new SQL server. I created a new web application for each and mounted the database to the web application.

Content wise, the databases work. I can see all the content and it functions properly. The only issue is trying to upgrade them.

Comment: you've not given us enough information,  can you post some logs to go with it?  anything in the event viewer?

Comment: Have you tried -force option? Some times psconfig fails the first time and goes smoothly second.